# DateTime.ToString() not working well for custom pattern and non-default system settings

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo, regional-settings

I am trying to get a string out of a `DateTime` object using the following C# code on .NET 4.5:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2015, 9, 30);
var str = dateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy");

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Under normal circumstances, the output of this code is 9/30/2015, as expected.

However, if I go to Control Panel, Region and Language and change the "Short date" pattern for US English to "dd-MMM-yy", the code above will suddenly display 9-30-2015!

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can fixed / worked around? Note, for instance, that if i choose in Region and Language another short date pattern such as "M/d/yy", the code works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` in your format string is treated as date separator and replaced with whichever separator is defined in Regional settings. You have to escape it with `\` (`\\`, to be precise)

Comment: You mean like this: `dateTime.ToString("M\\/d\\/yyyy")` ?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly now. Thanks a lot for your quick solution!